# SF1 sforce.one.createRecord and subscribing to publisher actions

Tags: salesforce1-app, canvas, publisher

I am having a issue subscribing to publisher events such as publisher.showPanel and publisher.post within SF1 when I fire a sforce.one.createRecord modal.

gist of sample code: https://gist.github.com/mtetlow/80789a679efe8e18465e

I get no console logging whatsoever when the createRecord modal fires. Essentially I am looking to fire a refresh of client side data when a new record is added via my ui. Does anyone have any idea if the publisher. events fire from the sforce.one.createRecord modal?

To recreate: create VF page with sample code, check available in SF1 on VF page, create tab for VF page, add tab to Setup -> Mobile Navigation. Then navigate to /one/one.app and click on your tab from the left side / hamburger menu. If you click the "Create Account" anchor, I would expect console logging to occur.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the only time the `publisher.post` event is fired is when the **Submit** button is clicked within a Salesforce1 custom publisher action.

There is currently no way to subscribe to `sforce.one` methods as they don't fire the `publisher` events, nor do they offer the facility to provide a callback method.

An alternative is to use [Visualforce Remote Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects.htm), [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/index_Left.htm) or [JavaScript Remoting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). All of which allow you to define callback functions.

---

Here are some examples (taken from the documentation linked above):

**Visualforce Remote Objects**

> ```
> var ctDetails = { FirstName: 'Marc', LastName: 'Benioff' };
> var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact();
> ct.create(ctDetails, function(err) {
>     if(err) { 
>         console.log(err);
>         alert(err.message);
>     }
>     else {
>         // this is the contact
>         console.log(ct.log());     // Dump contact to log
>         console.log(ct.get('Id')); // Id is set when create completes
>     }
> });
> ```

**AJAX Toolkit**

> ```
> var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");
> account.Name = "my new account";
>
> sforce.connection.create([account], {onSuccess : success, onFailure : failed});
>
> function success(result) {
>     if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
>         log("new account created with id " + result[0].id);
>     } else {
>         log("failed to create account " + result[0]);
>     }
> }
>
> function failed(error) {
>     log("An error has occurred " + error);
> }
> ```

**JavaScript Remoting**

> ```
> var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;
>
> Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
>      '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccount}', 
>      accountName, 
>      function(result, event){
>           if (event.status) {
>                document.getElementById('acctId').innerHTML = result.Id
>                document.getElementById('acctName').innerHTML = result.Name;
>           } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
>                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
>                event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
>           } else {
>                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
>           }
>      }
> );
> ```

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to use the standard object create actions within SF1, then figure out how to refresh my UI. I would rather not rebuild that entry screen if I could help it. I will continue looking to see if I can find any workarounds. Thanks for looking at it!